# Can i remove google play services language files?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, google-play-services

I've an android application and i use admob.
Do i need to include the entire languange pack located to `google-play-services_lib/res/values-COUNTRYCODE.xml`?

I tried to remove them and apk file resulted much smaller.

My app is currently served only in my country.

Answer (score 0):

Use resConfig "en" build configuration inside your app's build.gradle file.

This will instruct gradle to remove all other languages other than english. This immensely helps in reducing the size of the apk by upto 20-40% in some cases.